# Run time viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c

I am creating an app with a tab bar. However, when the app starts, I don't want it to display the tab bar. Instead I would like to show a login page. After a successful log in, the tab bar based application should be shown.

Is this possible in code? I did it with Interface Builder.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand the question. You wan't to do what?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a `Window-based Application` and create a ViewController with a TabBar that you can show once login is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Modal view controllers is the way you can do what you want. As it is said in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

> Modal view controllers are a tool that
>   you have at your disposal for
>   interrupting the current workflow and
>   displaying a new set of views.